# JS Function.prototype.apply() explanation

Tags: javascript

I'm a bit confused about this example:

```
Function.prototype.defer = function(ms) {
  let f = this; // I know content of this - it is function f
  return function(...args) {
    setTimeout(() => f.apply(this, args), ms);
  }
};

// check it
function f(a, b) {
  alert( a + b );
}

f.defer(1000)(1, 2);
```

I know that first this (let f) contains function f, but what about this in returned function? It is undefined as I understand, isn't it (`f.apply(undefined, args)`) ? If so, why should we use apply and why does it work?

Comment: *"...what about this in function-decorator?"* What do you mean by "function decorator"?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder a special function that takes another function and changes its behavior. Something like this

Comment: The second `this` is irrelevant. It's meant to provide context for the function to run in, but it isn't needed here. In this case, the second `this` will refer to the global `Window` object.

Comment: Like ***what***? `defer`? Note that "decorator" has a specific meaning in JavaScript (although that meaning is still being nailed down), and the above is not a decorator.

Comment: Your question is vague. Yes, the  second `this` will be undefined in the way you *use* that inner function. So what?

Comment: @trincot so I don't understand why such a call is used then

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, okay, thank you for your correction, but what about my question?

Answer (score 1):

> It is `undefined` as I understand

It is in your example use of of it.

> why should we use `call` and why does it work?

Not sure why you mention `call`. Maybe you intended `apply`. The reason is that you don't know know what `f` is and whether it needs some `this` binding, which depends on how it is called. It is nice to take that into account and not lose the `this` binding in the deferred execution.

Here is an example where the user of `defer` wants to use `this`:

```js
Function.prototype.defer = function(ms) {
  let f = this;
  return function(...args) {
    setTimeout(() => f.apply(this, args), ms);
  }
};

// check it
function f(a, b) {
  console.log(this + a + b );
}

f.defer(1000).call(3, 1, 2); // 6
```